# How to validate an SSH public key?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I've had issues copying public keys to `authorized_keys` and winding up with an extra linefeed or space or something.

Is there a way to simply validate that a key looks like a valid key? I don't have the private key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe `ssh-keygen -lf authorized_keys` is enough.

```
ssh-keygen -lf authorized_keys
key_read: uudecode AAAAB3Nzaf1a8eEABBABIwAAAQEA1y8gXks+s19QFdLP3ddei
  failed
authorized_keys is not a public key file.
```

(You may copy the respective line to a separate file before checking.) If the hashing function is too stupid to detect errors then converting back and forth may do:

```
ssh-keygen -ef id_dsa.pub -m PKCS8 | ssh-keygen -i -f /dev/stdin -m PKCS8
```

I expect that pipeline to fail in case of formatting errors.

Comment: Great - the first form detected the two error types.